# Chart image generation based on historical data?

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart, dynamic-image-generation

I was thinking about a back-end process that I can run once per day and generate/save to disk chart images similar to this:

[image: historical data chart]

Can this be done in Java or is there any other method that I am not familiar with?

Thanks!

Comment: [`org.jfree.chart.ChartUtils`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartUtils.html), formerly `org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities`, has several relevant methods.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the methods provided by [`org.jfree.chart.ChartUtils`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartUtils.html), formerly `ChartUtilities` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bjfreechart%5D%20org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities), to *save* completed chart images to the file system or *write* chart images to an output stream. Your application will suggest the appropriate space-time tradeoff, but nothing precludes your mixing strategies as need warrants.